# How to achieve multiline text view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to achieve user's caption, and comments like what instagram has but in swiftUI. But somehow the comments always truncated.

[image: img]

I already tried using `.lineLimit(nil)` but it didn't work.

```swift
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    Text(post.user.username).font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.bold)
    Text(post.description).font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.light)
        .lineLimit(nil).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
}
```

I expect it to be like this.
[image: ig]

Comment: You probably should use a ScrollView if the array of comments take up more than the available screen space.

Answer (score 11):

Add .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) to Text

Answer (score 3):

In order to have two `Text` objects on a single line, with multiple styling options, wrap onto a new line, you'll need to create multiple objects are combine them into one.

So take your two `Text` objects,

```
Text(post.user.username).font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.bold)
Text(post.description).font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.light)
    .lineLimit(nil).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
```

And we'll use `reduce`, to combine them.

```
func combineTextObjects(_ objects: [Text]) -> Text{
    return objects[1...].reduce(objects[0], +)
}
```

Call this `combineTextObjects` like this:

```
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    combineTextObjects([
        Text(post.user.username).font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.bold),
        Text(post.description).font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.light)
        .lineLimit(nil).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    ])
}
```

Comment: tried it, and it worked.
unfortunately when I added the `comments`, using the same method, it suddenly doesn't work again.

Comment: If you’re adding something else which is breaking this, it’s probably the other code, not this one. I use this in my app

Comment: When trying this I get an error: Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected element type 'Text'

Comment: @neptune they must not be proper text objects or you have a different error and SwiftUI is reporting wrong

Answer (score 3):

You can use () outside multiple text views to combine them and put multiline alignment outside ()...  hope this will help..

```
(
Text("More than ")
.font(.custom(FontManager.avenirRegular, size: 11)) +
                                        
Text("100 of your friends")
.font(.custom(FontManager.avenirDemiBold, size: 14)) +
                                        
Text(" have recently joined in your app!")
.font(.custom(FontManager.avenirRegular, size: 11))
)
.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
```